# How to handle PCs casually shopping in the market

Tags: dnd-5e, gm-techniques

Let's say that PCs are wandering the city market, looking for interesting items to buy. The DM has prepared a list of useful items that can be noticed with a successful combination of ability checks + time devoted to shopping + number of PCs actively searching. Some items are easier to be spotted than others. How can the DM handle this search in a balanced way? The average outcome would be that the PCs find just a subset of the list.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/65705/discussion-on-question-by-firion-how-to-handle-pcs-casually-shopping-in-the-mark).

Answer (score 38):

Here's how I generally handle things like this. But first, some advice:

**Keep It Short**

Finding some stuff in a market is not worth a giant skill challenge and time spent. If you want to invest actual time in shopping, make it *interesting* time with detailed NPCs and little sub-adventures (to the degree that your PCs are low level enough that basic fetch quests won't just cause them to go for mass murder instead).

You really have to ask yourself what the value is in making this a bunch of skill checks instead of just giving them a list of stuff they find after shopping for the day. By mechanizing this you just beg the question - they roll and find some stuff but clearly not all of it, so now they want to "try again," they want to focus on looking for weapons or magic or some other category you haven't sorted the items into... You run the risk of burning time for something that's not all that fun.

But if you are determined to do it, the trick to stuff like this is:

**Variable Difficulty**

Usually, the game wants you to set a DC and then roll against it. So the naive way is to have a list of items with a find DC for each one and then have the PCs roll perception for each one. Long and boring.

So what I do is set tiers of success based on the numbers at hand. "DC 10 you find one item, and then one more for every 5 points." You'd need to set the values based on a) the number of PCs rolling (or if you want others to Help, but of course more than one person helping doesn't yield any additional advantage), b) the number of items you have, c) about what the group's average Perception score is.

So if you have a list of 30 things, and you want them to find 15 of them on average, and you have 6 players, and their perception averages out to about +5 (6 rolls averaging 15), then saying each PC finds one item at DC 10 and one for every, say, 4 points over will get you around there. Vary the roll targets for different values of those constants.

**Choices Are More Interesting Than Rolls**

But, another but. Choices are more interesting than rolls. Let's say the party's looking at a week of downtime, and a player automatically finds one thing off the list for every half-day they spend shopping. But do all 6 of them want to spend a week shopping?  You'd have other things for them to do as well - learn spells, research adventure stuff, go hobnob in pubs... This way the PCs actually get to engage in what's going on in terms of what they value and what they're doing, not "woo I rolled a d20."  Rolls that don't really matter should not be rolls.

Comment: Great answer. This is a textbook example of how a frame challenge should go.

Comment: +1 for " Rolls that don't really matter should not be rolls," and if I could give two points I would for making interesting choices. I think that is the crux of what makes DnD (and RPGs in general) better than any other game.

Answer (score 17):

Consider the below, with the grain of salt that this is "Good DMing" guidance, not "these are the rules.":

- Is there the possibility of failure? It sounds like there probably isn't unless there are interesting things going on. If there is no possibility of failure if they just "take 10" as they stroll the market, it is an automatic success.
- Is there a real punishment for failure and not just trying again? If it's "would you like to roll again..?" is the punishment, that's not a punishment. This means an automatic success.
- Similar to the above, is failure interesting? If success means "adventure hook" and failure is "nothing interesting happens" then one is wasting time while the other is moving things forward. This gets back to "is failure interesting"

So if it's not worth rolling for, if it'll impede the campaign, or if it would generally succeed if they just kept looking around, don't make them roll for it. It's waste of your time and theirs, and it discourages exploration.

If you want the market to be interesting, consider it backwards. The market is encountering *them.* Have some weirdo chat with them, *but note that you should still apply the above logic.* If they can't fail, if there's no weight to a roll, don't roll for it.

Side Note: this goes to a greater philosophy of "don't have your players say 'I want to roll Blah'", have them describe their action and *you* decide what roll they are making. This encourages RP and interaction rather than game-speak and whatnot. If they want to intimidate someone, they have to do something intimidating. If the want to diplomacy someone, they better be telling the truth and saying a reasonable argument.

Another Note: I get a lot of my tips from reading TheAngryGM, and highly recommend it as a source of deep knowledge on the subject. It's also fairly entertaining to boot!

Comment: Indeed, this is very similar to the problems people get into when they *always* want a one on the d20 to mean critical failure... but there are very few things in day to day life where you have a 5% chance of dangerous injury while chopping wood, or walking, or shopping, or climbing stairs... but some people still insist on rolling for such things and to also involve critical failures.